# Fill in missing data in list

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

I have the sample data as shown in list format. This retrieve from api, but I need the data from **4am - 9pm** before save it to database. So I need to fill in data from 4am - 6am with 0 and last record time of the day until 9pm with the maximum value of the **day_power**.

The DateTime for the day will be inconsistent. Data from api might start & end at different time of the day as it is the values of inverter (solar panel output).

So how should I fill in the data?

Comment: You can use `List.Where(x=> condition)`, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0

Comment: What you have tried is far?

Comment: What do you need to do for the missing 17:00 record? Copy the previous `day_power`? What `Id` should the new records have?

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is the type of the data - `List<SomeClass>`?

Comment: Seems odd from a requirements standpoint to include power readings when the sun is set that match the highest power output of the day. Wouldn't that drastically overstate the power collected from the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from 4am are zero so that is easy.

Find the max value, and start from the end (9pm data) and assign it the max value if the entry is zero. Then move to 8pm etc, until you find a non-zero value.

For example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[] energy = new float[18];
        // 0 = 4am
        // 1 = 5am
        // ..
        // 16 = 8pm
        // 17 = 9pm

        energy[4] = 1.43f;  // 8am
        energy[5] = 1.52f;  // 9am
        energy[6] = 1.63f;
        energy[7] = 1.76f;
        energy[8] = 1.87f;
        energy[9] = 2.01f;
        energy[10] = 2.12f;
        energy[11] = 2.12f;
        energy[12] = 2.22f;
        energy[13] = 2.22f;

        FillValues(ref energy);

        Console.WriteLine($"{"Time",12} {"Power",12}");
        for (int i = 0; i < energy.Length; i++)
        {
            var time = TimeSpan.FromHours(4 + i);
            var power = energy[i];

            Console.WriteLine($"{time,12} {power,12}");
        }
    }

    static void FillValues(ref float[] data)
    {
        float max = data.Max();
        for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (data[i] < max)
            {
                data[i] = max;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with output

```text
        Time        Power
    04:00:00            0
    05:00:00            0
    06:00:00            0
    07:00:00            0
    08:00:00         1.43
    09:00:00         1.52
    10:00:00         1.63
    11:00:00         1.76
    12:00:00         1.87
    13:00:00         2.01
    14:00:00         2.12
    15:00:00         2.12
    16:00:00         2.22
    17:00:00         2.22
    18:00:00         2.22
    19:00:00         2.22
    20:00:00         2.22
    21:00:00         2.22
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can fill in missing values in a sequence using LINQ with `Enumerable.Range` to create the full range, and then doing some processing to fill in the missing values. In this case, I chose to create a list of the missing `DateTime`s using `Except`, and then process that against the original data, assumed to be `List<DayPower>`:

```
var startNewId = data.Max(d => d.Id) + 1; // for additional records
var startDateTime = data.First().DateTime.Date.AddHours(4); // first DateTime of range
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, 18) // full range of hours
                    .Select(offsetHours => startDateTime.AddHours(offsetHours)) // convert to range of DateTimes
                    .Except(data.Select(d => d.DateTime)) // remove DateTimes that already have data
                    .Select(dt => (dt, idx: data.FindLastIndex(d => d.DateTime < dt))) // find the lowest record with data proceeding each missing DateTime
                    .Select(dti => (dti.dt, dti.idx, dp: (dti.idx < 0) ? 0 : data[dti.idx].day_power)) // get the preceeding day_power or use 0 for new beginning records
                    .Select(dtidp => new DayPower { Id = startNewId++, day_power = dtidp.dp, DateTime = dtidp.dt }) // create missing objects
                    .Concat(data) // combine with existing data
                    .OrderBy(d => d.DateTime) // re-order by DateTime
                    .ToList();
```

NOTE: If you can assume the original data is in DateTime order, you can use `List.BinarySearch()` with an `IComparer` to find the preceeding record, but it probably isn't worth it for such a small amount of data.